# Run java in $PATH as an interpreter

Tags: java, shell

I want to make a script starting with a line:

```
#!java hogehoge.Hoge
```

In my machines of OS X and CentOS7, it runs.

But machines of CentOS6 give me an error:

```
./test.sh: bad interpreter: java
```

(My OS is JP so I omitted some of error messages but anyway it says java does not exist.)

All the environments are under zsh and 
of course, every $PATH contains a certain PATH like /usr/bin.
If I try a new script starting with:

```
#!/usr/bin/java hoge.Hoge
```

then it runs even in where the script with "java" does not work.

Does the difference come from the one between OSs?

or is there anything else that I do not realize?

Comment: The `#!` mechanism does not use $PATH.

Comment: Thank you. I should learn more... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java isn't a script interpreter, but you can run your java process with a script. Something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# export JAVA_HOME="/path/to/java_installation"
# export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
java hoge.Hoge
```

You may need to define JAVA_HOME and add it to your PATH (depending on your installation of Java).